# html entities not displaying properly

Tags: php, html, entities

I made a function for my website that converts special characters, in case someone will try to break out the system using colon, semicolons, single quotes or double quotes. I made an array of find which is the find variable in `str_replace` and change which will be exchanged.

```
$find = array('"','\'','<3');
$change = array('&quot;','&apos;','&hearts;');
$str = "This is a test ' " <3.";

$str = str_replace($find, $change, $str);
echo $str;
```

It literally prints the codes like &quot and supposedly it should be echoed as double quotes ("). I refreshed the page. It is still echoing the actual code.

Any help?

Comment: What does the *raw* server output look like? Try with `curl` on the command line or such to remove any confusion a browser might add.

Comment: What you mean?
can u add an answer directly so that i could learn something.

Comment: It's not an answer just yet, I'm asking you to debug more. Do you know how to use a command line to run `curl`?

Comment: Nope, i actually dont know what     curl is

Comment: Then forget that. Use "View Source" of your browser then to see the raw source the browser received. Note: *not "Inspect Element"* or such.

Comment: Just provide a answer. I cang understand view the raw source. You mean inspect element? There is no other way to view page source without inspect element.

Comment: if you press `ctrl + u` you can view page source

Comment: Nobody can answer your question, which is why I'm asking you to debug more! We need more information to diagnose this for you! Figure out how to "View Source" on whatever browser you're using (again, no information here). Tell us what exactly the source looks like.

Comment: For XSS protection, you should be using `htmlspecialchars`. (For your additional stuff, like replacing certain character combinations with named entities, you should use an additional function that runs after that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works, but you must to take care with the PHP quotes in the string:

```
$find = array('"','\'','<3');
$change = array('&quot;','&apos;','&hearts;');
$str = "This is a test ' \" <3.\""; // look at this line

$str = str_replace($find, $change, $str);
echo $str;
```

This works. See it working: http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=

Comment: the phpfiddle is missing the code query. Cant view it. And btw, what if someone enter the double quotes only like just typing the (") and clicking submit? It will still break the system.

Comment: You must to use `htmlentities()` function: http://php.net/manual/es/function.htmlentities.php To view how it runs in phpfiddle, just copy and paste my code in phpfiddle.org. I don't know how the link doesnt run

Comment: Thanks so much, great. Really appreciated this.